# Bootstrap: Progressbar loading doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my page i have a progress-bar, it has 3 part: `progress-bar-success`, `progress-bar-warning` and `progress-bar-danger`. I want that each part of this progress-bar will complete one by one, for example when `progress-bar-success` is complete then  `progress-bar-warning`be complete and then the last one be complete.

In my code i don't know where is wrong that it doesn't work correctly.

This is my code : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/21/)

How can i fix it?

**EDIT:**

I want this style for each of my progress-bar : [bootply](http://bootply.com/67388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the main problems in your original code:

- You should change the width of the progress bar div to update its status, not the width of your bar element.
- The progress bar div will not be affected by the container1 div's width, because the progress bar floats (if you check the container in your browser, you will find that it has no height) and it is set up to work together with the .progress class.

Here is a quickly fixed version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/30/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="person-info col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
         <div id="1" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
             <span class="sr-only">33.33% Complete (success)</span>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
         <div id="2" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
             <span class="sr-only">33.33% Complete (warning)</span>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
         <div id="3" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
             <span class="sr-only">33.33% Complete (danger)</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $bar = $('.progress-bar#1');
    var progress = setInterval(function() {
        if ($bar.width()<260) {
            $bar.width($bar.width() + 26);
        }
        $bar.text(Math.floor($bar.width() / 2.6) + "%");
        if ($bar.width()>=260) {
            $bar.parent().removeClass("active");
            if ($bar.is("#3")) {
                return clearInterval(progress);
            }
            $bar = $bar.parent().next().children(".progress-bar");
        }
    }, 520);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.person-info {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;

}
.progress{
    width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: i want 3 progress-bar complete one by one and when progress-bar-success be completed it is stay and doesn't remove.

Comment: @ElhamGdz Alright, so you want to have 3 bars on the screen? See updated answer for pointers why your code didn't work.

Comment: do you see shape of my progress-bar? i want when progress-bar-seuccess be completed then progress-bar-warrning be completed. but when i set your style in my code 3 progress-bar be completed together.

Comment: @ElhamGdz What do you mean? Should the previous one clear before the next one starts loading? In that case, just set its width to 0 before resetting the $bar variable. Oh, and here is one with the animation included: http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/30/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a stacked progressbar you can try my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/25/

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 0%">
    <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 0%">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete (warning)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 0%">
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var progress = setInterval(function() {
        var $successBar = $('.progress-bar-success');
        var $warningBar = $('.progress-bar-warning');
        var $dangerBar = $('.progress-bar-danger');

        if($successBar.width() < 160) {
            $successBar.width($successBar.width()+20);
        } else {
            if($warningBar.width() < 160) {
                $warningBar.width($warningBar.width()+20);
            } else {
                if($dangerBar.width() < 160) {
                    $dangerBar.width($dangerBar.width()+20);
                } else {
                    $dangerBar.width(160);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: why it doesn't complete and has empty space at the end?

Comment: I just posted as an example to show you how to increase individual bars. You don't want to use anything like the above in production, since you will want to tie your percentages to the actual loading completion amount. I amended the code slightly to make the progress bar a fixed width for you: http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/27/

Comment: when progress-bar be completed, it is not responsive and when i re-size page one of the progress-bar doesn't show.

Comment: when progress-bar-danger be completed it will disappear.why?